# How can I redirect to a URL when browser dose not support HTML5 videos?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

I am trying to redirect to a different URL when html5 video's not supporting. Actually HTML5 video are not playing in safari browser. So I want to redirect my page to home.html instead of index.html. Any help or direction My browser giving message `Your browser does not support HTML5 video`. Here is my code, any help will be appreciated.

**index.html**

```
<video id="myVideo" autoplay preload controls >
    <source src="final.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="final.ogv" type="video/ogg; codecs=theora, vorbis">
    <source src="final.webm" type="video/webm; codecs=vp8, vorbis">
       Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

Comment: try to ask to window.canvas ( for example), at the begin of page. And then if not redirect

Comment: have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33832452/html5-videos-not-working-in-safari

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 videos not working in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33832452/html5-videos-not-working-in-safari)

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the video element is supported in JavaScript, and then redirect if it isn't supported:

```
if (!document.createElement('video').canPlayType) {
  window.location.replace('home.html');
}
```